# Python Requests - Is it possible to receive a partial response after an HTTP POST?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I am using the [Python Requests Module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) to datamine a website. As part of the datamining, I have to HTTP POST a form and check if it succeeded by checking the resulting URL. My question is, after the POST, is it possible to request the server to not send the entire page? I only need to check the URL, yet my program downloads the entire page and consumes unnecessary bandwidth. The code is very simple

```
import requests
r = requests.post(URL, payload)
if 'keyword' in r.url:
   success
fail
```

Comment: The only way to do this is to close the TCP connection early, you cannot request that the server not send content (only the `HEAD` request lets you do that).  However, I would be extremely cautious about sending POST requests from a spider.

Comment: Are POST and GET interchangeable? Also, what do you mean by a spider and why should I be cautious?

Comment: POST and GET are **absolutely not** interchangeable.  Sending a GET request is "safe" -- it won't modify the web site, and if a webmaster sees a ton of GET requests then it's just traffic.  POST requests are used to add, modify, and delete content on the web, they often do some kind of action.  If a webmaster sees a lot of automated POST requests coming from one IP address, the webmaster might think that you are a spam bot or a hacker and report you to your ISP.  So I would be careful.

Comment: Try `prefetch=False` to avoid downloading the body immediately. The server probably redirects you after the post. Check `r.history` whether `requests` performs GET after the POST as browsers do. There is also `redirect` parameter though I don't know what it does for POST requests.

Comment: I set prefetch=False and used wireshark to capture the packets. Unfortunately, the server is sending me the same stuff regardless of whether I set prefetch or not.

Comment: you also need to close the connection. Here's [an example using `httplib`](http://ideone.com/KEQajG)

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution, if it's implementable for you. Is to go low-level. Use socket library.
For example you need to send a POST with some data in its body. I used this in my Crawler for one site.

```
import socket
from urllib import quote # POST body is escaped. use quote

req_header = "POST /{0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.yourtarget.com\r\nUser-Agent: For the lulz..\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: {1}"
req_body = quote("data1=yourtestdata&data2=foo&data3=bar=")
req_url = "test.php"
header = req_header.format(req_url,str(len(req_body))) #plug in req_url as {0} 
                                                       #and length of req_body as Content-length
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)   #create a socket
s.connect(("www.yourtarget.com",80))                   #connect it
s.send(header+"\r\n\r\n"+body+"\r\n\r\n")              # send header+ two times CR_LF + body + 2 times CR_LF to complete the request

page = ""
while True:
    buf = s.recv(1024) #receive first 1024 bytes(in UTF-8 chars), this should be enought to receive the header in one try
    if not buf:
        break
    if "\r\n\r\n" in page: # if we received the whole header(ending with 2x CRLF) break
        break
    page+=buf
s.close()       # close the socket here. which should close the TCP connection even if data is still flowing in
                # this should leave you with a header where you should find a 302 redirected and then your target URL in "Location:" header statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave some more data, for example, a sample URL that you're trying to request.  That being said, it seems to me that generally you're checking if you had the correct URL after your POST request using the following algorithm relying on redirection or HTTP 404 errors:

```
if original_url == returned request url:
    correct url to a correctly made request
else:
    wrong url and a wrongly made request
```

If this is the case, what you can do here is use the HTTP HEAD request (another type of HTTP request like GET, POST, etc.) in Python's `requests` library to get only the header and not also the page body.  Then, you'd check the response code and redirection url (if present) to see if you made a request to a valid URL.

For example:

```py
def attempt_url(url):
    '''Checks the url to see if it is valid, or returns a redirect or error.
    Returns True if valid, False otherwise.'''

    r = requests.head(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return True
    elif r.status_code in (301, 302):
        if r.headers['location'] == url:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        return False
    else:
        raise Exception, "A status code we haven't prepared for has arisen!"
```

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, additional detail on your requirements would help.  At the very least, this gets you the status code and headers without pulling all of the page data.

Comment: Using `HEAD` is of no help here as the requirement is to send form data and this requires sending `POST`.

Comment: @Piotr, this is why I want more information on his requirements--he right now does say that he is POSTing form information, but I'm speculating that that _might_ not be necessary, since in the comments on the original question he showed that he didn't know the difference between GET and POST--so maybe this requirement isn't guaranteed.  I did specify at the top of my answer the conditions to which this answer applied.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance the site uses [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. If so then it's enough to not follow redirect and read `Location` header from response.

Example

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/1', allow_redirects=False)
>>> response.status_code
302
>>> response.headers['location']
'http://httpbin.org/get'
```

If you need more information on what would you get if you had followed redirection then you can use `HEAD` on the url given in `Location` header.

Example

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/1', allow_redirects=False)
>>> response.status_code
302
>>> response.headers['location']
'http://httpbin.org/get'
>>> response2 = requests.head(response.headers['location'])
>>> response2.status_code
200
>>> response2.headers
{'date': 'Wed, 07 Nov 2012 20:04:16 GMT', 'content-length': '352', 'content-type':
'application/json', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'gunicorn/0.13.4'}
```