# why does the requests module fail at random with this website

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python to download some audio tracks from archive.org, here is one example of a link:
http://archive.org/32/items/goblinmarket_etk_librivox/goblinmarket_01_rossetti_64kb.mp3
In the browser this redirects to:
https://ia801601.us.archive.org/32/items/goblinmarket_etk_librivox/goblinmarket_01_rossetti_64kb.mp3
In my application I use this code:

```
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36', 'Accept':'*/*'}
v=requests.get(what[0], stream=True, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
```

Sometimes this works as expected (which is great!) other times though it hangs for a while before raising an error that goes along the lines of max retries exceeded with url.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to a way to fix this? The browsers load it without an issue.
Additional information: Usually it fails on the first try, but then works floorlessly after.

Comment: "Expires: Wed, 27 May 2020 07:04:30 GMT" Is there a delay of some kind between your requests?

Comment: it literally fails on the first request, but after that the second one is about 5 or 10 seconds after. I noted in chrome it sent a parcial response? would requests struggle with that

Comment: I am not sure, maybe try one of those solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170258/python-requests-is-it-possible-to-receive-a-partial-response-after-an-http-pos I also noticed that if I record the GET request in chrome it contains more information than you have in your code. You could also try to add them and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who experiences this in the future, following the comments posted  (for which I am very greatful), I had a look and added accept language, upgrade insecure requests, accept encoding and the max cache headers. One of these (not quite sure which one) but one of those fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone.