# Python requests - How to get shorter version of html page?

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I not get the full html page with `request` lib?
When I use `request.get()` in my code, it takes too long to respond.
How can I do it faster or how can I get some portion of html page using this lib?

Comment: You have no control over that. You get what the server serves to you.

Comment: As far as I know this shouldn't be possible with just `requests`. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13170258/5745575) is somewhat similar and might help you.